# Delphi Vcl to Firemonkey .TopItem workaround

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl

I'm fairly new to delphi and firemonkey. So far I'm hashing out my understanding by picking apart various examples. How should I go about converting this piece of code from Vcl to Firemonkey? The problem is that it uses .TopItem, and I've been searching around for a firemonkey .TopItem equivalent or a common workaround for its use but didn't find anything. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    procedure Tree2XML(tree: TTreeView);
    var
      tn : TTreeNode;
      XMLDoc : TXMLDocument;
      iNode : IXMLNode;

      procedure ProcessTreeItem(tn : TTreeNode; iNode : IXMLNode);
      var
        cNode : IXMLNode;
      begin
        if (tn = nil) then Exit;
        cNode := iNode.AddChild('item');
        cNode.Attributes['text'] := tn.Text;
        cNode.Attributes['imageIndex'] := tn.ImageIndex;
        cNode.Attributes['stateIndex'] := tn.StateIndex;

        //child nodes
        tn := tn.getFirstChild;
        while tn <> nil do
        begin
          ProcessTreeItem(tn, cNode);
          tn := tn.getNextSibling;
        end;
      end; (*ProcessTreeItem*)
    begin
      XMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
      XMLDoc.Active := True;
      iNode := XMLDoc.AddChild('tree2xml');
      iNode.Attributes['app'] := ParamStr(0);

      tn := tree.TopItem;
      while tn <> nil do
      begin
        ProcessTreeItem (tn, iNode);

        tn := tn.getNextSibling;
      end;

      XMLDoc.SaveToFile(ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(0),'.XML'));

    end; (* Tree2XML *)
```

Comment: edited to be more specific

Comment: Are you trying to walk the tree in some specific way?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to output the nodes to a structured XML file for loading when the program opens etc later.

Comment: Indeed, but what is special about the nodes you are selecting? Why do you need TopItem?

Comment: I don't necessarily, if there are better methods to achieve the same result. As I said, I'm fairly new.